# Dealing with conflicts on linux installs

Tags: linux, centos, yum, lame

I am trying to run a linux install.

I have added a rpm repo.

and i am running

```
yum install normalize
```

But i am getting the following error

```
    Transaction Check Error:
      file /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0 from install of libmp3lame0-3.99.3-23.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libmp3lame-3.98.4-4.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How do you deal with these types of errors?

I have tried

```
yum remove lame
```

Then re installed still getting the error.

Do i find the file and delete it i think the other lame was installed via ffmeg.

A bit lost and would appreciate some help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This show there is already same package installed with other version.

Try rpm -Uvh packagename*. This should low down your trouble.

Answer (score -2):

`yum remove lame` helped me in my situation on CentOS 6.5 x86_64.